# run java between windows and ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

i am running java source code on windows. Now I want it to run on Ubuntu but it doesn't work

**Below is the bat file on windows:**

```
@echo off
color 1f
title UC
C:\*****\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java -Xmx512m -Xms256m -Xss256k -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=./oom.hprof -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=200 -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -classpath "./;./lib/*;./config" com.playmore.http.jetty.SpringContextLoader
pause
```

**And here I switched to ubuntu .sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\e[34m"
echo -e "\e[1mUC\e[0m"
java -Xmx512m -Xms256m -Xss256k -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=./oom.hprof -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=200 -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -classpath "./:./lib/*:./config" com.playmore.http.jetty.SpringContextLoader
read -p "Press Enter to continue..."
```

**this is the error shown on ubuntu:**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.playmore.http.jetty.SpringContextLoader
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.playmore.http.jetty.SpringContextLoader
Press Enter to continue...
```

I don't know if it's because -classpath "./:./lib/*:./config" was not found or not, I hope it can run normally on ubuntu like windows

Comment: well, it needs a dependency that is not present on your Ubuntu; either add it in the jar, or add it in the classpath

Comment: Maybe the lib path on you Ubunty system is in a different level compare to your Windows, based on your current working directory

Comment: Have you checked what `ls . ; ls lib/* ; ls config` tells you about the classpath?

Comment: `.` is the current directory.  Since anyone can run your program with a current directory of their own choosing, your scripts are not reliable.  Use `-cp %~dp0;%~dp0lib\*;%~dp0config` in the .bat file, and use `d=\`dirname "$0"\`` followed by `-cp "${d}:$d/lib/*:$d/config"` in the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check if the class com.playmore.http.jetty.SpringContextLoader is present in the specified classpath on your Ubuntu system. Additionally, verify that the directory structure and file locations match

Answer (score -1):

Your error is in your quote usage. In most linux shells including bash, `"foo*"` will **apply that ***. A key difference is this:

- In windows, it is **the application** that applies star-globbing (so when you run `someApp *.txt`, windows' cmd.exe first breaks that apart into `someApp`, `*.txt`, will then use `$PATH` to figure out that you're referring to `C:\Program Files\foobar\someApp.exe` and will launch it, passing `*.txt` as args array. The `someApp` app then receives this and calls some windows API stuff to procure a list of files that match the glob `*.txt` and operates on each one.
- In linux, bash takes that line and breaks it into bits similar to windows, and uses `path` similar to windows to figure out which app to launch. However, **it is then `bash` itself that applies *.txt -> list of files conversion**, and bash will end up giving the `someApp` app as 'these are your command line args' the list: [`file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`].

(NB: This explains why using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` to pass `*.txt` to a linux process does not work: It's bash that applies globs, and ProcessBuilder is not bash).

bash still does this even if you use double quotes: The double quotes ensure that bash does not consider a space as a signal to go: End of one parameter, on to the next parameter. If you want bash to *also* cease attempting to 'interpret' the command line (which isn't just translating * to stuff, also `$FOO` and similar variable replacements), **you need single quotes**.

Because the classpath in java are colon separated (Semicolon on windows) and not space-separated, **bash mucks this up** - it sees that * and breaks it into separate arguments, which is not what java can handle.

Hence, java, uniquely, does its own `*` expansion. This is why it has to be just `*`, not `*.jar`, or `com.foo.*.jar` - bash can handle those but `java.exe`'s own system can only deal with `some/dir/*`.

And, because java does it, **you must tell bash *not* to**, and you do that with single quotes:

```bash
java -Xmx512m -Xms256m -Xss256k -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=./oom.hprof -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=200 -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -classpath './:./lib/*:./config' com.playmore.http.jetty.SpringContextLoader
```

Comment: You can also use backslash to escape the star, but single quotes are probably easiest here.

Comment: I have never seen wildcards expanded in double-quotes.  I just tried it in bash and there is no expansion.  Are you sure you aren’t thinking of a backtick statement?